# Using \zref in arguments of \ifnum (ranges)

Tags: cross-referencing, linguex, zref

Using `zref` I want to define a clever cross-ref command for ranges \clevestrip{ref1}{ref2} which returns a "stripping" string (1ab) if theExNo is equal for ref1 and ref2, and only prints ref1ref2 otherwise.

But there must be some issue with expandability because it does not work. If anyone can tell me why...

**Edited**
@Ulrike told me to use \zref@extract because \zref is not expandable, and it works like a charm.

MAWE (almost working...)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{zref-user}
\usepackage{philex}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{exno}{\arabic{ExNo}}
\zref@newprop{theexno}{\theExNo}
\zref@newprop{subexno}{\alph{SubExNo}}
\zref@newprop{thesubexno}{\theSubExNo}
\zref@newprop{subsubexno}{\roman{SubSubExNo}}
\zref@newprop{refskip}{\ifnum\theExDepth=3\roman{SubSubExNo}\else\alph{SubExNo}\fi}

\zref@addprops{main}{exno,subexno,subsubexno,theexno,thesubexno,refskip}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\refstrip}[2]{(\zref{#1}--\zref[refskip]{#2})}


\begin{document}

\phildashes{}{.} 
\subformat{a}{}{.}     


\lb{main1}{Example One.\zlabel{main1}
    \lba{sub11}{Subexample One-One.\zlabel{sub11}
        \lba{subsub111}{Subsubexample One-One-One.\zlabel{subsub111}}
        \lbb{subsub112}{Subsubexample One-One-Two.}
        \lbz{subsub113}{Subsubexample One-One-Three.\zlabel{subsub113}}} 
    \lbz{sub12}{Subexample One-Two.\zlabel{sub12}
        \lba{subsub121}{Subsubexample One-Two-One.}
        \lbz{subsub122}{Subsubexample One-Two-Two.}}}

\lb{main2}{Example Two. \zlabel{main2}
        \lba{sub21}{Subexample Two-One.}
        \lbz{sub22}{Subexample Two-Two.}} \zlabel{sub22}
        
        
\refstrip{sub11}{sub12}

\refstrip{subsub111}{subsub113}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\clevestrip}[2]{%
    \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{theexno}=\zref@extract{#2}{theexno}\refstrip{#1}{#2}\else\zref{#1}\zref{#2}\fi} % Using the expandable version (thanks to Ulrike Fischer)

\makeatother

\clevestrip{sub11}{sub12}   %   ERROR
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: commands with optional arguments are not expandable. If you want to retrieve the values in an expandable way you have to use the commands marked as "exp2" in the documentation, e.g. `\zref@extractdefault`.

Comment: Yes I was looking for this "exp" variant in the doc but couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the MWE replacing \zref by its expandable avatar \zrefextract, but with no success. Problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: you need the command which sets a default number.

Comment: I used \zref@extractdefault{#1}{property}{??} but it's not working either

Comment: Do you think \ifnum likes to see a `??`  ?  The default must be a number (and the command has three arguments).

Comment: Still not:
  \newcommand{\clevestrip}[2]{
 \ifnum\zref@extractdefault{#1}{theexno}{0}=\zref@extractdefault{#2}{theexno}{0}\refstrip{#1}{#2}\else\zref{#1}\zref{#2}\fi}
What is the 3rd argument I'm not following you?

Comment: You are missing the \makeatletter. And I would recommend not to use \ifnum (or other low level tex tests), it is easy to forget to correctly delimit a number or a test. Use etoolbox or expl3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I've learned with time is to always follow @UlrikeFischer's advice. Since she suggested you take a look at `zref-clever` in another question (which made my day :-), I think you should. Indeed, `zref-clever`'s `endrange` option seems particularly suited to solve the problem you are trying to solve.

The `endrange` option can receive a number of predefined values, such as `stripprefix`, or `pagecomp`, in which case it calls a processing function to build the end part of the range. But it can also receive a `zref` property (perks of `zref`), in which case you can pretty much build the end part of the range the way you want it. And, if using a `zref` property there is no need to process the reference in any way, so you don't need to guess the form it will take, or add a "marker" to be able to split it at the right point.

(I haven't the faintest of `philex` and `linguex`, I hope I'm not butchering them...)

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{philex}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{
  countertype={
    ExNo=example, % I'm assuming this is what "ExNo" means
    SubExNo=example,
    SubSubExNo=example,
  },
  counterresetby={
    SubExNo=ExNo,
    SubSubExNo=SubExNo,
  },
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{refskip}
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \value{ExDepth} } = { 3 }
      { \roman{SubSubExNo} }
      { \alph{SubExNo} }
  }
\zref@addprop{main}{refskip}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\zcRefTypeSetup{example}{
  endrange=refskip,
  rangesep={--},
  rangetopair=false,
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\phildashes{}{.}
\subformat{a}{}{.}

\lb{main1}{Example One.\zlabel{main1}
    \lba{sub11}{Subexample One-One.\zlabel{sub11}
        \lba{subsub111}{Subsubexample One-One-One.\zlabel{subsub111}}
        \lbb{subsub112}{Subsubexample One-One-Two.\zlabel{subsub112}}
        \lbz{subsub113}{Subsubexample One-One-Three.\zlabel{subsub113}}}
    \lbz{sub12}{Subexample One-Two.\zlabel{sub12}
        \lba{subsub121}{Subsubexample One-Two-One.}
        \lbz{subsub122}{Subsubexample One-Two-Two.}}}

\lb{main2}{Example Two. \zlabel{main2}
        \lba{sub21}{Subexample Two-One.}
        \lbz{sub22}{Subexample Two-Two.\zlabel{sub22}}}

\zcref[range]{sub11,sub12}

\zcref[range]{subsub111,subsub113}

\zcref{subsub111,subsub112,subsub113}

\zcref[range]{sub11,sub22}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well Gus that looks amazing, thanks a lot for this, I will try to understand because I have absolutely no clue what "\int_compare:nNnTF" is; can only guess this is about comparing two integer values. Also, what is "ExplSyntaxOn" ? Have seen this for a couple of days without figuring it out.
You know I do follow valuable advice and  I did have a look at that package, since it sounds so great to combine zref with cleveref ! But I didn't understand the doc :(

Comment: `\int_compare:nNnTF` is just an `expl3` version of your test (also following Ulrike's advice ;-).

Comment: Oh so this is it, since I have no idea what expl3 is, no wonder I'm totally lost here.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Well, technically, you can just use your previous definition of `refskip`, or take a look at `etoolbox`. I just "translated" the test.

Comment: Ah, `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`\ExplSyntaxOff` is the equivalent of `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` for `expl3` code.

Comment: I use `etoolbox` but for the moment nothing could solve this before zref. I had to combine all the posts and patch eveything between cleveref's mystriptocolon, `xpatch's` `\StrCut` and `refcount`'s `\getrefbykeydefault`... Really, `zref` changes my life you know, like a rainbow in the dark ^^

Comment: Oh so expl3 is another latex variant, like latex3 ?

Comment: expl3 is the new programming layer inside latex. Much new code is written with it. Look e.g. into siunitx or other new packages. Or into latex.ltx there you find some parts written in expl3 too.

Comment: @VincentKrebs It is LaTeX3, or the "LaTeX3 programming layer". It is part of the kernel nowadays, and `expl3` was the name of the package which provided it when it was still "experimental" (but I think the name just stuck around). Anyway, you don't have to use it at all (though it is better if you do), as I said, you can use your previous definition of the `refskip` property.

Comment: Oh I see, this is this stuff I recognize easily because it looks like hyeroglyphs to me. ;)

Comment: Actually, my "\refskip" stuff or the option `endrange` are useless here, `zref-clever` does it automatically :) This is a jewel, really.

Comment: Sorry endrange must be used, but `endrange =strippefix` makes my command useless, I will edit your answer ;)

Comment: @VincentKrebs I have not approved the edit because I thought it was a mistake. The reason is that `endrange=stripprefix` won't work for roman numbering, just like `\crefstripprefix` doesn't. And we had discussed this previously, hadn't we? ;-) So, using a `zref` property seems the clean way to handle the situation, imho.